# Powershell Email specific Error via log timestamp

Tags: powershell, logging, alert

```
$log = "C:\bobloblawslawblog.log"
Get-Content $log |
? {$_.Modified -le $(Get-Date).AddHours(-4)} |
Select-String "TCP" -Context 1 |
% { @($_.Context.PreContext) + @($_.Line)}
{
$Workstation = hostname
$emailSmtpServer = "mail.server"
$emailFrom = "Error CODE 1234@$Workstation.com"
$emailTo = "my.name@my.company.com"
$emailSubject = "$Workstation Error CODE 1234"
$emailBody = "$Workstation experiencing Error Code 1234"
Send-MailMessage -To $emailTo -From $emailFrom -Subject $emailSubject -Credential $credentials -Body $emailBody -SmtpServer $emailSmtpServer
$credentials= New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("username", $secpasswd)
}
```

I cannot seem to get this to grab the error from just the past 4hrs. The script grabs all the matching codes and sends them along.

The format of the timestamp in the log file is:

```
[2015-09-01 03:12:34,774] INFO com.server.mobilize.jte.service.listener.DesktopClientTransferListener(147) exception (Transport Protocol Seeker)- 218362: a warning or retriable exception has occurred Transfer warning: Error connecting to TCP Server-A/127.0.0.1:49221 relayed via Sever-B/External-IP:49221: Connection lost on tcp port read
```

I don't know what those last 3 numbers '975' indicate. It's not a pid.

What I want to do is have the script scrape a .log file - return a match from the last 4 hours and email an alert.

Ideally, I'd like the email body to include the actual error from the log.

Comment: Can you show us a line or two. Where does that timestamp appear on the line... at the beginning? Also the `Get-Content $log` is just a string array. Not an object that has a date property you can search on. Is it perhaps a csv or tab delimited file? We would need to parse that information out first before we can filter on it.

Comment: I feel there is a reason you chose to use `$_.Modified`

Comment: [2015-09-01 03:12:34,774] INFO  com.server.mobilize.jte.service.listener.DesktopClientTransferListener(147) exception (Transport Protocol Seeker)- 218362: a warning or retriable exception has occurred
Transfer warning: Error connecting to TCP Server-A/127.0.0.1:49221 relayed via Sever-B/External-IP:49221: Connection lost on tcp port read

Comment: `$_.Modified` will always be `$null` because `$_` is a string (it has no "Modified" proerty).

Answer (score 0):

Like I was saying in the comments you are trying access properties that don't exist in the pipeline. `Get-Content` returns a string array. Keep in mind that those whiles string do have special properties like `linenumber` there is no magical way that it interprets the date at the beginning. That is up to us.

```
Get-Content $log | ForEach-Object{
    # Extract the date
    $date = $null # Assume null

    # Match the data that occurs after the bracket and before the comma. This can only be at the beginning of the line.  
    If($_ -match "^\[(.*?),"){
        $date= [datetime]$matches[1]
    }

    # Build a new object as pass it along the pipe
    New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
        Modified = $date
        Line = $_
    }
}
```

Many ways to do this but I opted for creating a new object where we give it a modified property. We use regex to extract the date from the beginning of the line and cast it to a `[datetime]` so that you can now perform date calculations.

Assuming  the rest of your logic does what you want it to you just need to append it after the last `}` in my snippet above.

**Something a little better**

Making another object seemed like a waste of resources so I used the same logic in the `Where` instead. I have also added the `Select-String` portion of you code as well. I made some changes.

```
$results = Get-Content $log | Where-Object{
    # Match the data that occurs after the bracket and before the comma. This can only be at the beginning of the line.  
    $date = $null
    If($_ -match "^\[(.*?),"){$date = [datetime]$matches[1]}
    $date -gt (Get-Date).AddHours(-4)
} | Select-String "tcp" -Context 1 | ForEach-Object{
    "{0}`r`n{1}`r`n{2}" -f ($_.Context.Precontext -join "`r`n"), $_.line, ($_.context.postcontext -join "`r`n")
}
```

Now results will have just that. So you would see in there all entries that have occured in the last 4 hours that have the string "TCP" somewhere on the line. It will also include the line before and after the match. `$results` has the potential to be an array so you would need to account for that in your email. A simple `` $results -join "`r`n" `` would do it.

Comment: I wish I could say I understand powershell and programmatic logic better, however I am not able to assemble this code structure in a way that produces results I can use.

Comment: This snippet gives me the results from the log file I need but without a time filter.
    $log = "C:\useful_log.log"
    Get-Content $log |
    Select-String "TCP" -Context 1 |
    % { @($_.Context.PreContext) + @($_.Line)}

Comment: @Steve I will look into putting the parts together for you. Can you at least see how the output of my code works? I mean without your logic.

Comment: unfortunately my exposure is pretty limited. I think I need an extended intro course. Once descriptions get into If / Then / Else and parsing objects I get lost pretty fast.
I've made a few scripts in the past but none of them were ever all that complex. My last successful script searched a log for the absence of successful windows activation and emailed the team.

Comment: Everyone has to start somewhere. I learned PowerShell to the degree I due purely from this site. Research the individual parts of the code to get a better understanding. Documentation is always dry but the understanding is there.